# Change bibtex in-text citation reference

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing

I'm using this bst file which provides the unified style sheet for linguistics style as my bibliography style for my term paper http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.linguistics/1047 but it's citation reference in the text which links to the full source in the bibliography does not fulfill the requirements set by the department.

When I use, for example, `\cite[p.194]{Biber.1999}` it shows as `(Biber, 1999, p.194)`.
I would like to change it to this `(Biber 1999: 194)`.

Edit: Tried to do a minimal example as requested:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}

   % setup for my title page 

\end{titlepage}

% Table of Contents
\tableofcontents \thispagestyle{empty} \setcounter{page}{2}
% 

% List of Tables/Figures
\listoffigures
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\listoftables
\endgroup
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures / Tables}
% 

%some more sections here
\newpage \section{textbody}
  ....  \cite[p.194]{Biber.1999} ...
\newpage \section{Biblography}
\bibliography{bibly}

%some more sections here

\bibliographystyle{unified}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. You have to make changes in the bst file (which is complicated), but if that file was given to you, this is the desired result.

Comment: By the way, `biblatex` is much easier to handle.

Comment: That file was not given to us, only that we have to used the "unified style sheet for linguistics" for the bibliography style and how we have to refer in the text to the references.

Comment: @Seph: The link you provide directly leads to `unified.bst`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I changed the link in case that this is what to wanted to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than doctor the `unified` bibliography style file, I believe it's much easier to (a) load the `natbib` citation management package, (b) issue the command `\setcitestyle{notesep={: }}` to set the connector between the reference and the supplementary information (such as a page number), and (c) define a custom citation command -- called `\mycite` in the example below -- that provides the citation callout format you need.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{biber.1999,
  author = "Biber",
  year   = 1999,
  title  = "Sharp teeth rule!",
  journal= "Dead Trees Are Us",
  volume = 1,
  number = 1,
  pages  = "1-100",
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{notesep={: }}

\newcommand\mycite[2]{(\citealt[#2]{#1})}

\bibliographystyle{unified}
\begin{document}

(\citealt[194]{biber.1999})  % direct form

\mycite{biber.1999}{194}  % using the macro \mycite

\mycite{biber.1999}{} % if no suppl. note, leave second argument blank

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{aysep={},notesep={: }}
```

and `unified.bst` you get what you need using `\citep` for (Author Year: 123), `\citet` for Author (Year: 123), `\citealt` for Author Year: 123.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{author,
author = "Author",
year   = 2000,
title  = "Title",
journal= "Journal title",
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{aysep={},notesep={: }}

\begin{document}
\citet[123]{author}, \citep[123]{author}, \citealt[123]{author}

\bibliographystyle{unified}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```